# Linux kernel: How to get dev_t of whole disk from partitioned disk?

Tags: linux-device-driver, device-driver, procfs, sysfs, block-device

I want to retrieve the `dev_t` structure for a whole disk, given that of a partition on the disk.  This is for for a `blkext` driver,  like `nvme`.

Something like:

```
dev_t part_disk;
dev_t whole_disk = get_whole_disk_dev_t(part_disk);
```

I would like my the interface of `get_whole_disk_dev_t()` to be:

Argument: `dev_t`: *part_disk*
Return: `dev_t`: *whole_disk*

My proposed algorithm:

1. Get path of partitioned disk from `dev_t` i.e "/dev/nvme1n1p3".  I couldn't find any API to get path from `dev_t`.
2. Do some string manipulation to remove "p3", giving the path for whole disk
3. Pass the path_name of whole disk to `blk_lookup_devt` to get the `dev_t` of whole disk.
   i.e `whole_disk=blk_lookup_devt(path_name,0)`

Is this the right approach or is there a better approach? If the former, then how can I get path from `dev_t`?

P.S: I need to implement this in a device driver (i.e in kernel context). In user space I know I can use the `udev` API.

Comment: [get_gendisk](http://astro.temple.edu/~tue68607/wiki/html/kernel-api-2.6.29/re530.html) May be this is what you are looking for :-)

Comment: get_gendisk is not exported, so can't use it :(

Comment: Read diiferent APIs May be you will find what you needed [Block API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/blkdev.html)

Comment: thnks for the help :) finally done with the code :)

Comment: your welcome.Happy to listen that :-) Upvote any comment if it is helpful to you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static int hello_init(void)

{

dev_t devno;

struct block_device *bddev;

struct gendisk *bddisk;

char disk_major[32];

devno=MKDEV(252,67);

printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world .... current devno is %x \n", devno);

bddev=bdget(devno);

if(bddev) {

    bddisk=bddev->bd_disk;

    if(bddisk) {

         strcpy(disk_major,bddisk->disk_name);

         printk(KERN_ALERT "bddisk is present %s", disk_major);

     } else {

       printk(KERN_ALERT "bddisk is not present");

    }

} else {

printk(KERN_ALERT "bdev failed ");

}

devno = blk_lookup_devt(disk_major,0);
printk(KERN_ALERT "after blk_lookup_dev:  dev_t: 0x%x  Major No %d   Minor No %d \n", devno, MAJOR(devno), MINOR(devno));

return 0;

}


static void hello_exit(void)
{

printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, world\n");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem: you can read /proc/partitions file, obtain needed sd[a|b|c]
drive id. Suppose, that id:
char devId[] = "sdb"
after that invoking devno = blk_lookup_devt(devId, 0);